# Java Spring classpath resource path to folder

Tags: java, spring, resources

If we would like to use relative path to file we use following code:

```
@Override
public void setRootFolderResource(Resource rootFolderResource) {
    try {
        this.rootFolder = rootFolderResource.getFile().getAbsolutePath();
        log.info(String.format(ROOT_FOLDER_RESOURCE, rootFolder));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error(String.format(ROOT_FOLDER_RESOURCE_EXCEPTION, e.getMessage()));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And bean config:

```
<bean name="fileClient" class="com.myproject.clients.FileClientImpl" depends-on="propertyConfigurer" scope="prototype">
    <property name="rootFolderResource"><value>${storage.path}</value></property>
</bean>
```

Where:

```
storage.path=classpath:data/data.txt
```

it works for file data.txt. How to do we change code if we need path to folder?:

```
storage.path=classpath:data/foldername
```

Comment: What happens if you try what you've shown?

Comment: It just get following:

    threw exception; nested exception is   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1